# javax.servlet.ServletException: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.example.Person

Tags: java, hibernate, glassfish

i'm using hibernate with mysql, but when i've created webapplication and had deployed it on glassfish i've got this error

```
[2014-02-19T18:30:54.170+0100] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=19 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1392831054170] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[FacesServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.example.Person
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:693)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1485)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:713)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:697)
    at com.example.personManager.addPerson(personManager.java:30)
    at com.example.PersonFormBean.addPerson(PersonFormBean.java:38)
    at com.example.PersonFormBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.addPerson(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
]]
```

My Person class looks like this:

```
package com.example;


import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;



@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int yob;



    public Person() {
    }
    public Person(String name, int yob) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.yob = yob;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getYob() {
        return yob;
    }
    public void setYob(int yob) {
        this.yob = yob;
    }


}
```

Person manager:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class personManager {

    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    Session session;
    Configuration configuration;

    public personManager() {
        try {
            configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration();
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Person.class).configure().buildSessionFactory();
            sessionFactory = configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Person.class).configure().buildSessionFactory();

            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public void addPerson(Person p) {
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(p);
        try {

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Saving failed." + ex);
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public void deletePerson(Person p) {
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(p);
        try {

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Saving failed." + ex);
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Person> getAll() {
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("select p from com.example.Person p");
        List<Person> result;
        result = query.list();
        return result;
    }

}
```

and personFormBean:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;
import javax.inject.Named;

@SessionScoped
@Named("personBean")
public class PersonFormBean implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Person person = new Person();

    private ListDataModel<Person> persons = new ListDataModel<Person>();

    private personManager pm = new personManager();

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public ListDataModel<Person> getAllPersons(){
        persons.setWrappedData(pm.getAll());
        return persons;
    }

    public String addPerson(){
        pm.addPerson(person);
        return null;
    }

    public String deletePerson(){
        Person personToDelete=persons.getRowData();
        pm.deletePerson(personToDelete);
        return null;

    }

}
```

and this is my hibernate configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">michal12</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping class="com.example.Person"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Somebody know what's wrong here?
I'll be verry greatful for help.

Answer (score 1):

Your entity was not scanned by Hibernate. Use in Session factory

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example" />
```

or

```
configuration.addPackage(packagesToScan);
```

And add `@GeneratedValue` to the `id` field of the entity.

Comment: I'm not used to Java Configuration for Hibernate or whatever. I suggest you to make all your constructors logs something like "I'm created with dependencies:"+.... Then you can see. Another question I have is: Where is your xml loaded?

Comment: Which xml? hibernate.cfg.xml? it is loaded in src, together with com.example package. Or you mean other xml file?

Comment: I've used mapping files instead of @Entity annotation and now it works. I do not know why glassfish had problem with annotations and told me that entity is unknown.